# Multifile.js jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, multifile-uploader

I am using multifile.js jquery plugin to upload multiple files. However when the size is large say 7MB it doesn't seem to work. Is it normal behaviour for this plugin. Is there any other option for this kind of task.

Comment: Is there a limit on your server for upload file size? I found that when I used it, I had to make sure my server accepted files up to the size I was specifying in multifile.js.

Comment: Forgot about the limit of 4 MB on asp.net. Just changed the limit in the webconfig and it worked.

Comment: Great! Added as an answer. Please accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a limit on your server for upload file size? I found that when I used it, I had to make sure my server accepted files up to the size I was specifying in multifile.js.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) for uploading multiple files. It has many helpful options such as only allowing certain extensions, queuing of files being uploaded, and it is also customizeable if you dont want to use the default design.

Also I have never had issues with large files.